# How to make list active and inactive onclick for the data with loop in angular7

Tags: html, angular

I have few list in ul li coming from loop,When I click any of the list it should be active again when I click other, previous should be inactive and current should be again active like tabs,I have tried active is working but inactive is not working properly,Can anyone please help me,here is the code

### app.component.html

```
<ul>
  <li  *ngFor="let row of groups;let i = index" [ngClass]="{'active': row.isClicked}" (click)="row.isClicked = !row.isClicked">{{row.items}}</li>
  </ul>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component,ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent  {
groups = [{"id":1,"name":"pencils","items":"red pencil","Status":[{"id":1,"name":"green"},{"id":2,"name":"red"},{"id":3,"name":"yellow"}],"loc":[{"id":1,"name":"loc 1"},{"id":2,"name":"loc 2"},{"id":3,"name":"loc 3"}]},{"id":2,"name":"rubbers","items":"big rubber","Status":[{"name":"green"},{"name":"red"}],"loc":[{"name":"loc 2"},{"name":"loc 3"}]},{"id":3,"name":"rubbers1","items":"big rubber1","Status":[{"name":"green"},{"name":"red"}],"loc":[{"name":"loc 2"},{"name":"loc 3"}]}]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let row of groups;let i = index" [ngClass]="{'active': clickedIndex == i}" (click)="clickedIndex == i? clickedIndex = null : clickedIndex = i">
     {{row.items}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

`clickedIndex` holds the index of the clicked `li`. 'active' class is applied only when `clickedIndex`  is the index of that `li`. If you are clicking again the active `li`, then `clickedIndex` is changed to null so that it is no more active

See [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ucoa9a)

Comment: Looks nice too, Even can be decreased to <li *ngFor="let row of groups;let i = index" [ngClass]="{'active': (clickedIndex == i)}" (click)="clickedIndex = i">{{row.items}}

Comment: See edited answer :D I just did that and posted the link. Added another condition to unselect `(click)="clickedIndex == i? clickedIndex = null : clickedIndex = i"`

Comment: I need one more help,first list should be active on load of page

Comment: Okay... I am adding that

Comment: Add `clickedIndex: number = 0` in the typescript

Comment: Also I answered your new question. Check

Answer (score 0):

You should run through all entries in list and set `row.isClicked = false` on them.

move handler `(click)="row.isClicked = !row.isClicked"` to the component and enhance 
it with something like:

```
this.rows.forEach(row => row.isClicked = false);
selectedRow.isClicked = !selectedRow.isClicked;
```